# Google Admin SDK Error 401 when trying to authorize

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am using the Google Admin SDK Reports V1 Api to gather all admin activities from the Google Apps admin panel.

My Google Api python client was recently updated to version `"google-api-python-client (1.5.1)"`

Previously I was using the following:

```
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

serviceAccountEmail = "blahblablah1233324@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
key = "google-apps-file.p12"
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly']


credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    serviceAccountEmail, key, scope=scopes, sub=userEmail)
```

Then Google dropped support for SignedJwtAssertionCredentials. So I switched to this.

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

serviceAccountEmail = "blahblablah1233324@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
key = "google-apps-file.p12"
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(
    serviceAccountEmail, key, scopes=scopes)`
```

Ok so this should be a relatively easy small code change, however when I ran the code I get the following error.

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 137, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 832, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 401 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/admin?alt=json returned "Access denied. You are not authorized to read activity records.">
```

So no permissions have changed, one thing I am noticing though is the original code is asking for a `sub=userEmail` (which is an account to impersonate, that account would have specific admin privileges over the Google Apps domain.)

It would make sense that I would get the `401` however there is no mention of a `sub=userEmail` parameter in the new documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I realized what I was missing.

Originally I had

```
 f = open(serviceAccountKeyLocation, 'rb')
 key = f.read()
 f.close()
 # Packaging up the auth parameters to pass along with the request.

 credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(serviceAccountEmail, key, scope=scopes, sub=userEmail)
 http = credentials.authorize(http)
 return http
```

I then did some reading up and further research.

Then replaced it with this.

```
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(serviceAccountEmail, 
                                                             serviceAccountKeyLocation,
                                                             scopes=scopes)
delegate_credentials = credentials.create_delegated(userEmail) # this fixes the sub user
http = delegate_credentials.authorize(http)
return http
```

The version of the Google Api python client I was running was still making use of `from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials` while the new updated version uses `from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials`.